# Large Excel files- is Access a better platform for data analysis

Tags: excel, performance, ms-access

I have an excel file w/ 600k line items (about 15 columns). Opening it, much less performing analysis is extremely slow on my not-exactly-a-super-computer (doing a simple VLOOKUP on 1/3 of the dataset takes 10 min and will often crash). I have Access 2010 at my disposal. Is that a) suitable for inputting weekly data and returning some basic summary stats (SKUs rolled up by plant) and, b) significantly faster than an Excel workbook w/ 500k-1M rows?

Comment: Yes on all accounts.  Move to Access or better yet Sql server.

Answer (score 1):

I won't advise moving from to Excel to Access , SQL server or oracle will be better because it seem like you do have a large database to handle and you also want Speed and consistency. Moving your data from Excel to SQL server will be great.

Comment: Surely Access is better than Excel? I'm mainly considering that since options are limited at my work. Does SQL server require a license and knowledge of SQL programming?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server is free of download however they do charge for premiem users.